# regex recursive match with backreference

Tags: regex

I have the following regex

```
\s([^:]*)\s?r?:([0-9]+)(?=.*\1:-([0-9]*))
```

to match a string like

```
start x.foo:100 aa x.foo:101 aa y.bar r:300 aa y.bar:-600 aa x.foo:-202 aa x.foo:-200 z.zoo:250 z.zoo:-500 end
```

I want to get the inner x.foo:101 and inner x.foo:-202 to be given in a match
and the outer x.foo:100 anf x.foo:-200 to be another match

Could you pls help change the regex to achieve this

Comment: Does your string always have the same amount of x.foo:123? Or are the numbers always the same?

Comment: no numbers will change..also in some cases there might be more nested foo as this string is passed to server by user

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with one simple pattern, so I suggest using this pattern in a loop - depending on your programming language

```
.*?((\S+):\d+)(.*)(\2:-\d+)|.+$
```

and replace w/ `$3` or `\3` depending on you engine, what your looking for is sub-patterns 1 & 4

```
MATCH 1
1.  [6-15]  `x.foo:100`
2.  [6-11]  `x.foo`
3.  [15-75] ` aa x.foo:101 aa y.bar r:300 aa y.bar:-600 aa x.foo:-202 aa `
4.  [75-85] `x.foo:-200`
MATCH 2
1.  [86-95] `z.zoo:250`
2.  [86-91] `z.zoo`
3.  [95-96] ` `
4.  [96-106]    `z.zoo:-500`
```

replacement result will look like this:

```
` aa x.foo:101 aa y.bar r:300 aa y.bar:-600 aa x.foo:-202 aa  `
```

now running the loop using the same pattern on the results will get you

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-13]  `x.foo:101`
2.  [4-9]   `x.foo`
3.  [13-46] ` aa y.bar r:300 aa y.bar:-600 aa `
4.  [46-56] `x.foo:-202`
```

and so on, remember only use sub-patterns 1 &4 and break the loop when there are no more matches.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/232)